# OpenMP Parallel error: missing increment expression

Tags: c, parallel-processing, openmp

I'm trying to pass the code to list prime OpenMP numbers, I have two problems,

- The first problem is to remove the Break and that the code works
- the second problem is that marks this error `error: missing increment expression`
- List item

  in the line of `for (count = 2; count <= n;)`

  // If I add an expression as count ++ code does not work correctly.

Here is my codes :

```
int n, i = 3, count, c;
// n is the number's prime
for ( count = 2 ; count <= n ;    )
{
    for ( c = 2 ; c <= i - 1 ; c++ )
    {
        if ( i%c == 0 )
            break;

    }
    if ( c == i )
    {
        printf("%d\n",i);
        count++;
    }
  i++;
}
```

}

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is. Can you please rephrase it to be more accurate? Also, you could format the code correctly so it is easier to read.

Comment: What are "cousins OpenMP numbers"?

Comment: @Carlos your algorithm is unsuitable for parallelization. You will have to search for a different one to make it work with OpenMP.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the rest of the code, but:

- If you delete the increment in the first FOR loop, the error is obvious. You cant delete that. "count ++" is mandatory.
- Check if the initial valor of count is less than n (i.e: if "n" is 1, and you start with count =2, the FOR loop will not start)
- Be careful: in the first IF block, you are trying to modify the value of "count", but that variable is being used by the FOR loop to control the remaining iterations. As I said, it depends on the code functionality, but usually you dont want that to happen (modify a loop-control variable)

Without further information, I'm afraid we wont be able to help you more.re.